# Can I create FFTW variables dynamically?

Tags: fft, fftw

I am trying to implement the FFTW alforithm for the Fast Fourier Transform in some simulation. The FFTW works with its own type called `fftw_complex`. An object of this type would be declared as:

```
fftw_complex object[N]
```

I want this object to be part of some class:

```
class Species{
    public:
        Species(std::string name, double mass, double charge, long number, World &world);
        
        /*STUFF*/
        
        fftw_complex direlec[world.N], tranelec[world.N];
    protected:
        World &world;
}
```

where N is a member of another class `World` whose value has already been established with the World constructor. If I write something like this, the compiler gives the error:

> [Error] 'world' was not declared in this scope

How can I get the value of `world.N` in the class declaration? I can't create the `complex_fft` object in the constructor since it must know the number `N` already in the declaration. Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider dynamically allocating the required array with [`fftw_malloc`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Memory-Allocation.html)?

Comment: First, the declaration you specified is not for an object, but for an array of fixed size N. Second, is `N` a data member of a `World` class/struct (e.g. field)? If yes, then it absolutely cannot, and it is a C++ language trait: array sizes are static and must be known at compile-time. If you want to have a dynamic array, you should use `fftw_malloc` as mentioned by @SleuthEye - it also provides sufficient alignment for SIMD instructions (SSE2, AVX, etc).